# %mend statement in SAS macro

Tags: macros, sas

```
%macro A1(input);
[balala]
%mend A1;


%macro A1(input);
[balala]
%mend;
```

I just realized both ways work for defining a macro. Is there any difference between these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically, there is **no difference**, you can use any of the two. But as a good programming practice you should use first one as it helps in identifying where the  macro ends.

If you are using the first one, just remember to put the same name after [`mend`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000206958.htm) that you have used for `macro`, otherwise `SAS` will issue a `Warning`.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000206958.htm

Answer (score 2):

No, there is absolutely no difference. All of these work technically the same.

```
%mend;
%mend <macroname>;
%mend <something else>;
```

The possibility to put macro name there exists only for clarity purposes.

That might be useful when you have long macros or you define macros inside other macros (which in my opinion is almost always bad practice).

For example these are exactly the same but of course the first is very confusing but SAS correctly warns you that probably something needs to be fixed:

1)

```
%macro OuterMacro;
    %macro submacro;
        %put 1;
    %mend OuterMacro;
%mend submacro;
```

2)

```
%macro OuterMacro;
    %macro submacro;
        %put 1;
    %mend submacro;
%mend OuterMacro;
```

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/68140/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n01mgvwt7f9smen159ad334ts4ha.htm